# Failed in adding bootstrap in package.json using npm

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, npm

I am currently trying to learn react and I cannot add bootstrap as a dependency in my package.json using npm. I am trying the command `npm install bootstrap` in my terminal and I am in my current project directory. Here is the error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/lan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/lan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'bootstrap',
1 verbose cli   '--save'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose npm-session 2a73fc2953f50908
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap 470ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for bootstrap@^5.0.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."shx":"^0.1.2","time-'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 596ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."shx":"^0.1.2","time-'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (/home/lan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at /home/lan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
12 verbose cwd /media/lan/3561-3761/WebProjects/LearnReact
13 verbose Linux 5.8.0-53-generic
14 verbose argv "/home/lan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/home/lan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm" "install" "bootstrap" "--save"
15 verbose node v14.17.0
16 verbose npm  v6.14.13
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."shx":"^0.1.2","time-'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am currently in a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS OS.

Comment: try npm cache clean

Comment: check the syntax of your package.json file. its look like you have some unexpected chars there